# Display multiple lines in SKLabelNode

Tags: swift

I checked there is no properties for multiline in SKLabelNode. 
Is it possible to display multiple lines in SKLabelNode?

If no, Please give idea to display text in multilines.

Answer (score 2):

I use this bit of code to get multi lines of code with SKLabelNode.
 [Multilines in a label-github](https://github.com/downrightsimple/DSMultilineLabelNode)

Answer (score 2):

There is a way now to do multi-line SKLabelNodes.

Set the property numberOfLines to 0. From Apple's documentation:

> The default value is 1 (a single line). A value of 0 in interpreted as an unlimited number of lines. If the height of the text reaches the number of lines, the text will be truncated using the line break mode.

Comment: Well, you are right, I thought SKLabelNode does not have this property like UILabel in UIKit, but I learned it has. Thanks.